# How to show pictures in a Lightbox without an TYPO3 Extension in v7.6

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I want to build a "picture-gallery" with the normal Media CE Content Element without an Extension. I was first trying several Extensions from the TER (like MagnificPopUp ... a.o.), but for my needs there are too much overheads i don't need.

How can i use the normal lightbox script for that?

Thanks for your help

BR

Comment: This is opinion based question. Check TYPO3 TER and return with questions to a specific extension, in case you have some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not you need an extension. This can easily archived without one.

Put the following in your constants:

```
styles.content.textmedia.linkWrap.lightboxEnabled = 1
```

Put the following in your setup:

```
page.includeJSFooterlibs {
    lightbox = fileadmin/templates/Public/JavaScript/lightbox.min.js
    jsFile.async = 1
}
```

You can find a possible lightbox implementation here (but any will do): http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

You can find there a sample CSS file too, easy to adapt to your wishes.